# Adding parts of a second to time

Tags: vba, excel, time

I am writing an excel VBA script, and I would like to add parts of a second to a time extracted from a cell.

I am using the time function to divide the content by 2, and then convert using the Time function, and add the result to the current time.

```
tt = Time(0, 0, Cells(1, 12) / 2)
```

I get a type mismatch error, as the result of the division is not an integer.

what I would like to do at the end is to perform the following addition.

```
newTime = timeCurrent + tt
```

Is there any alternative to the Time function to be used in this case ?

Comment: what is format of `Cells(1, 12)` and `timeCurrent`?

Comment: timeCurrent is hh:mm:ss, Cells(1, 12) is a number

Comment: so if you want to add seconds to a current time , if i understood properly you could use [**DateAdd()**](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php) function like `DateAdd("s", timeCurrent, Cells(1,12)`? is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub TimeOnMyHands()
    Dim tt As Date
    tt = TimeSerial(0, 0, CInt(Cells(1, 12).Value / 2))
    MsgBox Format(tt, "hh:mm:ss.000")
End Sub
```

assuming the cell contains seconds as a simple number rather than a time value.

Comment: Now THERE is an accurate function name ;)